# Can't understand why list view is not rendered. (backbone js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I'm trying to create a simple list view, it looks to me like i'm doing everything by the book, however it doesn't work. Please help me understand the flow. Final template should look like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>Search history</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Hello!</li>
      <li>Hello!</li>
      <li>Hello!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>Search history</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This one is main view:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'doT',
'history/record/record_view',
'history/history_collection',
'text!history/history.html',
], function ($, _, Backbone, doT, RecordView, HistoryCollection, HistoryTemplate) {
var searchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#history',

    template: doT.template(HistoryTemplate),

    initialize: function () {
        this.$hl = this.$('.list');
        this.history = HistoryCollection;
        console.log('History view initialized...');
        this.render();

        this.listenTo(HistoryCollection, 'sync', this.fill);
        this.listenTo(HistoryCollection, 'change', this.fill);
        this.history.fetch();
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        console.log('History rendered...');

        return this;
    },

    addOne: function (data) {
        var view = new RecordView({model: data.toJSON()});
        this.$hl.append(view.render().el);
    },

    fill: function(){
        this.$hl.empty();
        this.history.each(this.addOne, this);
    }

});
// Our module now returns our view
return searchView;
});
```

List template:

```
Hello!
```

Here is a list code:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'doT',
'history/history_model',
'text!history/record/record.html',
], function ($, _, Backbone, doT, Model, RecordTemplate) {
var recordView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: doT.template(RecordTemplate),
    model: Model,
    initialize: function () {
        //Inits
        console.log('Record view initialized...');
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
        console.log('Record rendered...');
        return this;
    },

});
// Our module now returns our view
return recordView;
});
```

Comment: I was looking at your `recordView` view and noticed what might be your problem. Try changing `this.model` in the `render` method to `this.model.toJSON()` or `this.model.attributes`.
Honestly I've not looked closely at this, so it's just a maybe :).

Comment: it seems that you specified an unexisted element > el: '#history',
Create a wrap your main div <div class="panel panel-default">
with <div id="history">

Comment: Thanks! This one helped.